# Reduce the amount of parquet files in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-blob-storage

Parquet files have been created in Azure Blob storage with partition by date using pyspark in databricks but received so many files like 500 files in one date folder. I need to reduce the amount of files using PySpark like 10 or 15 files in one date folder.

```py
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Date").save(
    "/mnt/mydata.parquet"
)
```

I tried with `coalesce`:

```py
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Date").coalesce(15).save(
    "/mnt/mydata.parquet"
)
```

But an error is thrown:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'coalesce'

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce) is a method of `dataframe` object :

```
df.coalesce(15).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Date").save("/mnt/mydata.parquet")
```

If you're having some memory error, then consider using a `repartition` instead.